# Unity Monetization. Arial.ttf is no longer a valid built in font. Please use LegacyRuntime.ttf

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When calling `Monetization.Initialize(gameId, testMode)`, I receive this error "Arial.ttf is no longer a valid built in font. Please use LegacyRuntime.ttf". I have checked online to no avail. How can I fix this? thank you

This is the full error

```
ArgumentException: Arial.ttf is no longer a valid built in font. Please use LegacyRuntime.ttf
UnityEngine.Advertisements.Placeholder.CreateButton (UnityEngine.GameObject canvasGameObject, System.Int32 x, System.Int32 y, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEngine.Vector2 anchorMin, UnityEngine.Vector2 anchorMax, System.String buttonText, UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction onButtonClick) (at <91220002a2fd403abd0d44e0c6cd5f2c>:0)
UnityEngine.Advertisements.Placeholder.CreatePlaceholder (UnityEngine.GameObject canvasGameObject, UnityEngine.Texture2D texture, System.Int32 textureWidth, System.Int32 textureHeight) (at <91220002a2fd403abd0d44e0c6cd5f2c>:0)
UnityEngine.Advertisements.Placeholder.Awake () (at <91220002a2fd403abd0d44e0c6cd5f2c>:0)
UnityEngine.Advertisements.Advertisement:Initialize(String, Boolean)
Starter:StartMonetization() (at Assets/Scripts/POBSystem/Starter.cs:402)
<Start>d__140:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/POBSystem/Starter.cs:385)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
UniRx.Async.Internal.ReusablePromise:TryInvokeContinuation() (at Assets/UniRx.Async/Internal/ReusablePromise.cs:102)
UniRx.Async.Internal.ReusablePromise:TrySetResult() (at Assets/UniRx.Async/Internal/ReusablePromise.cs:89)
UniRx.Async.DelayPromise:MoveNext() (at Assets/UniRx.Async/UniTask.Delay.cs:155)
UniRx.Async.Internal.PlayerLoopRunner:Run() (at Assets/UniRx.Async/Internal/PlayerLoopRunner.cs:67)
UniRx.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0:<InsertRunner>b__1() (at Assets/UniRx.Async/PlayerLoopHelper.cs:91)
```

Comment: Do you have a valid licence to distribute Arial.ttf? Perhaps it is time to choose a different font which you can get a valid licence for.

Comment: ok thank you. How can I change the font that is used by UnityEngine.Monetization to a different one?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error from a different script.
I searched for "Arial.tff" in that script and replaced it with "LegacyRuntime.tff". It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading from Unity Monetization package to Unity Advertising package 4.4.2 which fixed the error. However, I had to upgrade my game code to use Advertisement package instead of the monetization package